# NSIS: How to press "Next" button automatically when MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES is complete

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm making an installer with NSIS and have the following pages:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

On each page must press the "Next" button.

How to press "Next" button automatically when installation is complete in MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES?

Comment: Thanks you for asking this question.  Google takes me to the NSIS MUI documentation but a search within it doesn't find a description of MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you defined `MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE` in your script?

From the [manual](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html):

> `MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE`
>
> Do not automatically jump to the finish page, to allow the user to check the install log.

Comment: I removed this command and solved. Thanks for understanding my problem.